# Extract specific values from a excel/csv table to form another table in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have an excel sheet with the below table.

```
Sort,Realm,Subrealm,Kingdom,Subkingdom,Phylum,Subphylum,Class,Subclass,Order,Suborder,Family
1,,,Virus,,Negarnaviricota,Haploviricotina,Chunqiuviricetes,,Muvirales,,Qinviridae
2,,,Virus,,Negarnaviricota,Haploviricotina,Milneviricetes,,Serpentovirales,,Aspiviridae
3,,,Virus,,Negarnaviricota,Haploviricotina,Monjiviricetes,,Jingchuvirales,,Chuviridae
4,,,Virus,,Negarnaviricota,Polyploviricotina,Ellioviricetes,,Bunyavirales,,Phasmaviridae
5,,,Virus,,,,,,Caudovirales,,Ackermannviridae
6,,,Virus,,,,,,Caudovirales,,Myoviridae
7,,,Virus,,,,,,Caudovirales,,Siphoviridae
```

I would like to extract data in the expected result format.

```
Sort,Name,Rank,Parent
1,Negarnaviricota,Phylum,Virus
1,Haploviricotina,Subphylum,Negarnaviricota
4,Polyploviricotina,Subphylum,Negarnaviricota
1,Chunqiuviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
2,Milneviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
3,Monjiviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
4,Ellioviricetes,Class,Polyploviricotina
1,Muvirales,Order,Chunqiuviricetes
2,Serpentovirales,Order,Milneviricetes
3,Jingchuvirales,Order,Monjiviricetes
4,Bunyavirales,Order,Ellioviricetes
5,Caudovirales,Order,Virus
1,Qinviridae,Family,Muvirales
2,Aspiviridae,Family,Serpentovirales
3,Chuviridae,Family,Jingchuvirales
4,Phasmaviridae,Family,Bunyavirales
5,Ackermannviridae,Family,Caudovirales
6,Myoviridae,Family,Caudovirales
7,Siphoviridae,Family,Caudovirales
```

**Description of Extracted Columns:**

1. Sort - Number associated with the unique name being extracted
2. Name - Unique names from each column that has a name
3. Rank - Header of the column where the name is extracted from
4. Parent - Last non-blank value in the preceding cells

```
first_row = ['Realm', 'Subrealm', 'Kingdom', 'Subkingdom', 'Phylum', 'Subphylum', 'Class', 'Subclass', 'Order', 'Suborder', 'Family', 'Subfamily', 'Genus', 'Subgenus', 'Species']

df1 = pd.read_csv('ictv-msl-2018-v1.csv', index_col='Sort')
print('Writing to CSV File')
with open('dp1.csv', 'w', newline="") as tbl_writer1:
    c2 = csv.writer(tbl_writer1)
    c2.writerow(['Name', 'Rank'])
    for list_item in first_row:
        for item in df1[list_item].unique():
            row_content = [item, list_item]
            c2.writerow(row_content)

with open('ictv-msl-2018-v1.csv', 'r',) as inp1, open('dp1.csv', 'r') as inp2, open('dp2.csv', 'w', newline="") as out1:
    msl_tbl = csv.DictReader(inp1)
    tbl_data = list(msl_tbl)
    c3 = csv.writer(out1)
    for row in csv.reader(inp2):
        if row[0] != 'nan':
            c3.writerow(row)
        else:
            print('Deleted Row:', row)

df2 = pd.read_csv('dp2.csv')
print(tbl_data[0]['Species'])
print(len(df2), len(df2.columns))
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df2.columns)):
        print(df2.get_values()[i][j], i, j)
```

Can someone please advise how I can extract all four of the below columns? The above code only extracts `Name,Rank`

`Sort,Name,Rank,Parent`

Comment: What output are you getting, or errors, if any? For all we know your code works...you haven't asked a question.  Provide all information about the problem.

Comment: The output of my code currently only prints `Name,Rank`. I would like to print all four columns `Sort,Name,Rank,Parent`. Hope this helps. I have also updated the question for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your original input data as `input.csv`:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv',newline='') as fin:
        r = csv.reader(fin)
        header = next(r)
        names = {}
        for row in r:
            parent = None
            for idx,content in enumerate(row):
                if idx == 0:                   # First column is sort.
                    sort = content
                    continue
                if not content:                # Skip blanks.
                    continue
                if parent is None:             # Record the first non-blank content as parent.
                    parent = content
                    continue

                # Remaining content is names.
                # Record name the first time it is seen,
                # then update parent.
                data = sort,content,header[idx],parent
                if content not in names:
                    names[content] = data
                parent = content

def sortkey(data):
    sort,name,rank,parent = data
    return header.index(rank),int(sort)

with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    w = csv.writer(fout)
    w.writerow('Sort Name Rank Parent'.split())
    for data in sorted(names.values(),key=sortkey):
        w.writerow(data)
```

Output:

```
Sort,Name,Rank,Parent
1,Negarnaviricota,Phylum,Virus
1,Haploviricotina,Subphylum,Negarnaviricota
4,Polyploviricotina,Subphylum,Negarnaviricota
1,Chunqiuviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
2,Milneviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
3,Monjiviricetes,Class,Haploviricotina
4,Ellioviricetes,Class,Polyploviricotina
1,Muvirales,Order,Chunqiuviricetes
2,Serpentovirales,Order,Milneviricetes
3,Jingchuvirales,Order,Monjiviricetes
4,Bunyavirales,Order,Ellioviricetes
5,Caudovirales,Order,Virus
1,Qinviridae,Family,Muvirales
2,Aspiviridae,Family,Serpentovirales
3,Chuviridae,Family,Jingchuvirales
4,Phasmaviridae,Family,Bunyavirales
5,Ackermannviridae,Family,Caudovirales
6,Myoviridae,Family,Caudovirales
7,Siphoviridae,Family,Caudovirales
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That works great. You did not use pandas either.